# Query from New York Times API (JSON) giving same output on different search keywords?

Tags: javascript, json, api

I am trying to get JSON data from new your times API. Below is the query I am using. Its edited from the example query from their website.

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx = is the api key which I replaced for obvious reasons.
"search_city_name" = the where I am supposed to put my search keyword as I understood so far.

Problem : no matter what I am trying to search in the query I am getting same result.
Query:

```
http://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json?q="search_city_name"&sort=newest&&api-key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

for example this is the first object of the response array I get no matter what string I paste instead of "search_city_name":

```
_id: "553a537238f0d87fad3b3cd7"
abstract: null
blog: Array[0]
byline: Object
document_type: "article"
headline: Object
keywords: Array[1]
lead_paragraph: "Cokie Roberts’s “Capital Dames,” No. 10 on the hardcover nonfiction list, is about powerful women in Washington during the Civil War era."
multimedia: Array[2]
news_desk: "BookReview"
print_page: "26"
pub_date: "2015-05-03T00:00:00Z"
section_name: "Books"
snippet: "Cokie Roberts’s “Capital Dames,” No. 10 on the hardcover nonfiction list, is about powerful women in Washington during the Civil War era."
source: "The New York Times"
subsection_name: "Sunday Book Review"
type_of_material: "News"
web_url: "http://www.nytimes.com/2015/05/03/books/review/inside-the-list.html"
word_count: "480"
```

Update:
Working version of query:

```
"http://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json?q="+ city +"&&api-key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

Comment: http://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json?[q="search_city_name"&sort=newest&&api-key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

you do need to put a valid api which you can get free from the site to get the results from a query.

Comment: provide more of your javascript code, the response is not as relevant

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald If I just paste the query in my browser with desired keyword and correct api I can get the JSON data inside the browser. The javascript code just pasre the data. So does not really need to paste it. If you Still want I can but seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example given in the [docs](http://developer.nytimes.com/docs/read/article_search_api_v2) is `http://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.response-format?[q=search term&fq=filter-field:(filter-term)&additional-params=values]&api-key=####` Normally square brackets indicate optional arguments. I bet if you remove those it will actually understand what you're sending and work.

Comment: I removed some parameters and it indeed worked. "http://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json?q="+ city +"&&api-key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
 Now i am just thinking what was causing it to fail?

Comment: it is because you had the square brackets

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Get method to get Data from API, then it gives u cache data from previous call,

So please use "post" instead of get or make cache false for specific request.